# Docker compose fails to setup container links properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I recently started with Docker Compose and followed the introductions of the official docs. The first example I did (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)) defines two containers inside *docker-compose.yml* and if I understand them right, the containers are linked by default. Their .yml looks the same as mine:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    depends_on:
    - redis
  redis:
   image: redis
```

However, using docker exec in order to take a look inside the running web container reveals that there's no DNS entry for redis in */etc/hosts*. I'm also not capable of doing a ping to the redis container by name, it only works for the container's IP address. This is my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.3      e886da2c2a78
```

I've also examined the bug reports at Github, but the suggestions I found didn't work for me so far. I can exclude the possibility that is has to do with any firewall issues, since *firewalld* is not running on my host.

Any ideas?

My setup:

- Docker version 1.11.1
- Docker Compose version 1.7.1
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 on Oracle VirtualBox on Win7

Comment: Did you try using links instead of depends_on. If I am not mistaken, depends_on just defines the starting order of the containers, but doesn't make a link via /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Hi @bartimar. Yes I already tried, but no success.

Comment: The hosts file is not altered for container-container communication, it is done by internal DNS resolution by docker's DNS service I believe, so checking the hosts file won't show anything even if it's working. Strange that ping doesn't work. I'll see if I can reproduce in a minute.

Comment: I think in docker 1.10+, the new embedded DNS is taken the role of managing container addresses, so you can not see the linked containers within the /etc/hosts
I have encountered an issue specific to nginx, which try to resolve the name via IPv6 while docker's DNS only support IPv4

Comment: @JHarris Right, I also read that minutes ago. Keep me up-to-date with your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe
```

If I use your `docker-compose.yml` file verbatim, and the following `Dockerfile` to give `docker-compose` something to `build:`...

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update darkhttpd
CMD ["darkhttpd", "/var/www/localhost/htdocs"]
```

Then I start everything up:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

And then enter the web container:

```
$ docker exec -it outofbounds_web_1 sh
```

And then ping `redis`:

```
/ # ping -c 1 redis
PING redis (172.20.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms

--- redis ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.166/0.166/0.166 ms
```

It all Just Works.

As was mentioned in the comments, there are no modifications to `/etc/hosts` because name resolution is now handled via dns lookups.

Comment: you can do `$ docker exec -it outofbounds_web_1 ping -c 1 redis` as well :))

Comment: Yes.  The point is that name-based service discovery should work out of the box, and you shouldn't need to use the id-based hostname (like "c8e728098d19") as you suggested in the comments on the question.

Comment: @larsks doing a ping to *redis* works for me now after a restart. Before, I got "unknown host" error. Thx for help!